# Corrupt table mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a big problem into my MySQl table.
If I try to do

```
SELECT * FROM ORDININUOVO
```

I have this message:

[image]

Now how can I fixed it?

> EDIT
>   I'm try to start the command REPAIR TABLE ORDININUOVO;

but this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps: `REPAIR TABLE ORDININUOVO`? Don't take my word for it, read the manual, carefully.

Comment: please try `REPAIR TABLE ordininuovo`

Comment: Also check that there is space left on the harddrive where the file resides, or it will just go corrupt again.

Comment: I have just EDIT my question

Comment: What is the table engine?

Comment: @RaymondNijland I use MySql 5.5.35

Comment: that's mysql version..table engine is MyISAM or InnoDB

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/422507/mysql-incorrect-information-in-file-corrupt-error

Comment: EngineTable = InnoDB